# Vertical align text in input on Safari is different from the others browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I have problem with vertical align text in input only on Safari browser with custom font (Sofia Pro).

If font-size is small everything is ok, when i change font-size for example: **100px** vertical align is bad.

Placeholder in input has vertical align correct but value of input is not good.

Custom font was generated by https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator, i tried another web font generators but results were the same.

There is example: http://test-site0.orionhub.org:8000/test/index.html.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: This issue also occurs in Matlab: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/734170-why-is-text-vertically-misaligned-when-i-use-a-custom-font, but there does not seem to be any solution as of today and the font has not been updated.